# How to avoid Copy in Derived class operation?

Tags: c++

I have the following class structure:

```
class Base{
public:
    Base() {}

    Base(const Base& b){
        cout << "Base Copy" << endl;
        *this = b;
    }

    Base baseOperation(Base& base){
        return Base();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    Derived(){}

    Derived( const Base &d ) : Base(d)
    {
        cout << "Derived Copy: " << endl;
    }

    Derived operation(Derived& input){
        return baseOperation(input);
    }

};
```

Base is basically a library I am using. It has an operator called baseOperation, that takes in itself and returns an output; I want to wrap around that output but without making both a copy of base and of derived. It is making double copies now which slows my program down. Is there a way to avoid this

Comment: Why don't you call the copy constructor of `class Derived` in `Derived operation(Derived& input)` directly?

Comment: Note that your constructor writing `"Derived Copy"` is a *conversion constructor*, not a copy constructor.

Comment: As for your "problem", are you sure it's a problem? Normally modern compilers are very good at return value optimizations like [*copy elision*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). Have you *measured* that this is really a bottleneck of your code?

Comment: I use a similar concept for something like a "virtual copy constructor" (to realize a [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)). For this, the base class provides a `virtual clone() const` method which has to be overridden in any derived class. However, every overloaded `clone()` method has the exact same behavior: calling the copy constructor with `*this`.

Comment: Could you give me an example. I cannot modify my base class though

Comment: @Raaj It's impossible. If the base version returns a base object, you must create a new Derived/Base object and copy the state over. There are no exceptions.

Comment: Are you sure it slows your program down? For me it looks like prematrue optimization.

Comment: @raaj btw, does the base have a move constructor? If no I guess you can't do anything more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only copy here could be while constructing Derived object in the return statement of

```
Derived operation(Derived& input){
    return baseOperation(input);
}
```

All other copy operations are eliminated by RVO. Of course you can change copying to moving if you have access to sources of `Base`. But maybe it is worth to consider *aggregation instead of inheritance*.